# Retrieve field from xml using SQL Server 2005

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, xpath

I've got the following sql code:

```
declare @x xml
set @x = 

'<ResultBlock>
    <MatchSummary matches="1"><TotalMatchScore>900</TotalMatchScore>
        <Rules totalRuleCount="9">
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_SWTEL_DEMP_DEADD</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_MS</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_PAS_MS</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_CTEL_MS</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_REF</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_PAS_REF</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_CTEL_REF</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_MS_PER</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score>
            </Rule>
            <Rule ruleCount="1" isGlobal="1">
                <RuleID>MA_REF_PER</RuleID>
                <Score>100</Score></Rule>
        </Rules>
        <MatchSchemes schemeCount="1">
            <Scheme>
                <SchemeID>7</SchemeID>
                <Score>900</Score>
            </Scheme>
        </MatchSchemes>
    </MatchSummary>
    <ErrorWarnings>
        <Errors errorCount="0" />
        <Warnings warningCount="0" />
    </ErrorWarnings>
</ResultBlock>'

select  x.value(N'RuleID', N'varchar(50)') as RuleID
from @x.nodes(N'//RuleID') t(x)
```

I need to retrive all the `RuleID`'s. But the following query generates an error:
`XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'`. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close - your XPath returns a list of all the `<RuleID>` nodes as XML fragments - now you want to extract the actual element value, so you need to use this SQL XQuery to achieve this:

```
select 
    x.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as RuleID
from 
    @x.nodes('//RuleID') t(x)
```

The `.` says : *just give me the contents of the element* - that's what you're looking for, right??